# Checking a list with null values for duplicates in C#

Tags: c#, linq, list

In C#, I can use something like:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();

if (myList.Count != myList.Distinct().Count())
{
    // there are duplicates
}
```

to check for duplicate elements in a list. However, when there are `null` items in list this produces a false positive. I can do this using some sluggish code but is there a way to check for duplicates in a list while disregarding null values with a concise way ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I'd do this differently:

Given Linq statements will be evaluated lazily, the `.Any` will short-circuit - meaning you don't have to iterate & count the entire list, if there are duplicates - and as such, should be more efficient.

```
var dupes = myList
    .Where(item => item != null)
    .GroupBy(item => item)
    .Any(g => g.Count() > 1);

if(dupes)
{
    //there are duplicates
}
```

EDIT: http://pastebin.com/b9reVaJu Some Linqpad benchmarking that *seems* to conclude `GroupBy` with `Count()` is faster

**EDIT 2: Rawling's answer below seems at least 5x faster than this approach!**

Comment: +1 I prefer this to the other answers, seems more succinct to me.

Comment: The `Any` still requires the whole input to be iterated at least once (to build the groups), and some portion of it to be iterated a second time (to check the length of groups - although on second thought maybe the groups can shortcircuit `Count` without iterating) - whereas it's possible to perform this check with *at most* a single iteration of the whole input.

Comment: @Rawling I assumed since Count() is evaluated as part of the 'Any' - it would evaluate the grouping lazily - how could we test this? it's Quite interesting!

Comment: Well, you can use `ILSpy` to look for the implementation of `GroupBy`, but think about it this way - before `GroupBy` can return the first group, it needs to have consumed the entire input sequence in order to make sure it has all the items that will go into that group.

Comment: @Rawling How could they shortcircuit `Count()` when it has to return the exact count of items in the group? Though you could write an extension method like `bool CountAtLeast(int)`, which would shortcircuit.

Comment: @svick I mean that, since `GroupBy` reads all the items into groups, I'd hope `Count()` on a group would act like `Count()` on a list i.e. return an existing `int` rather than iterate through all the items counting them. "Short-circuiting" wasn't the best phrase to use :)

Comment: I've just ran some benchmarks on this approach & the Count()/Distinct() version - the GroupBy seems about 10% faster in my little tests (when there are dupes).

Comment: @Rawling or, use `Skip(1).Any()`, no `HashSet` required. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16960723/659190

Comment: @Jodrell Skip seems consistently slower in my benchmarks - this surprised me. http://pastebin.com/b9reVaJu

Comment: @Jodrell That will still require `GroupBy` to read and group the whole input. Further, if `Count()` is optimized on a group (which I think is likely) then `Skip(1).Any()` will be slower than `Count() > 1`.

Comment: Dave, I'm not surprised if your `GroupBy` version is faster than the two Count() versions, and your upvoters probably wouldn't be surprised by it either :)

Comment: @Rawling, your assertion is true but, at what sequence length/item size does the `HashSet` allocation pay off.

Comment: @Jodrell I'd expect immediately, as both `Distinct` and `GroupBy` also need to build up some kind of hash of the values.

Comment: Why don't just check index of a null element like in my solution below? It looks better and works faster I think :)

Answer (score 56):

If you're worried about performance, the following code will stop as soon as it finds the first duplicate item - all the other solutions so far require the whole input to be iterated at least once.

```
var hashset = new HashSet<string>();
if (myList.Where(s => s != null).Any(s => !hashset.Add(s)))
{
    // there are duplicates
}
```

`hashset.Add` returns `false` if the item already exists in the set, and `Any` returns `true` as soon as the first `true` value occurs, so this will only search the input as far as the first duplicate.

Comment: I thought `GroupBy` was deferred?

Comment: @Jodrell It is deferred up until the point you try to read the first group, at which point it reads the entire input sequence, groups it, and returns the first group.

Comment: in that case, the `HashSet` is required.

Comment: @DaveBish Oh, thanks for going to the trouble of benchmarking it :)

Comment: +1 This will give the best performance for very large collections.  But not necessarily for small collections due to the overhead of creating / updating / reallocating the HashSet.

Comment: @Joe `Distinct` does essentially the same thing with a `HashSet` under the hood, and `GroupBy` will do something similar as well.

Comment: This is the best answer and I loved it.

Answer (score 11):

```
var nonNulls = myList.Where(x => x != null)
if (nonNulls.Count() != nonNulls.Distinct().Count())
{
    // there are duplicates
}
```

Comment: this iterates the list twice though

Answer (score 4):

Well, two nulls are duplicates, aren't they?

Anyway, compare the list without nulls:

```
var denullified = myList.Where(l => l != null);
if(denullified.Count() != denullified.Distinct().Count()) ...
```

Comment: I can think of lots of situations not to consider nulls duplicates. We have a site where users can login via email or (optional) username. Users without a username have null for username, but no username can be duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** my first attempt sucks because it is not deferred.

instead,

```
var duplicates = myList
    .Where(item => item != null)
    .GroupBy(item => item)
    .Any(g => g.Skip(1).Any());
```

---

<s>poorer implementation deleted.</s>

Comment: @svick however, thats not lazy enough.